# D3.js: draw simple line graph starting from data arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two arrays, one containing the data which should go into the X axis, the other the data which should become the Y entries.

How can I tell d3.js to take the data from those arrays and use it as data for its graph and then draw it?

Comment: You are going to need to merge the data into a single array

Comment: Which type of visualization do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use anything on top of D3?  If so, check out http://c3js.org.  C3 is built on top of D3, and it makes creating simple charts much easier.

Comment: and dimple.js as well. I've yet to use either c3 or dimple, but these sort of libraries built on top of D3 do seem super-useful.

Comment: This, sir, seems really useful, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to solve a similar problem. I've assembled the code I used and put it into a fiddle. However, I'm not a d3 expert and so while I can say this works, it might not be the best method. Furthermore, since I built this, I've found things like C3 and Dimple, as mentioned by John Grese in another answer, and those libraries could prove more useful for you.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cf7a4afv/

It takes two arrays of data:

```
var x_data = [1,2,3,4,5,5.5,7,8,9,12]
var y_data = [1,5,4,6,4,3,5,6,7,8]
```

This data can build a simple line graph where the points (1,1), (2,5), (3,4) etc are plotted as (x,y) coords and joined by a line. I've thrown in a few edgecases, like x=5.5 and a jump from x=9 to x=12 to show that this method is quite flexible.

Then there are two functions that can turn each data point into a pixel on screen. These are based on the height and width of the graph:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(x_data)]).range([0, w])
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(y_data)]).range([h, 0])
```

Then this gets turned into a line function. The key thing here is that the y function returns data from the y_data array; this is how we can use two arrays to create one graph.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
        return x(d)
    })
    .y(function(d, i) {
        return y(y_data[i])
    })
```

Then there is some SVG manipulation and w,h calcs - these are all in the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! At the end i chose to use c3.js insted, which seems really easier. Anyway, you response was very appreciated.