# d3.js line chart with two arrays

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

This questions not unique I agree. It has been answered in this link: [D3.js: draw simple line graph starting from data arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418892/d3-js-draw-simple-line-graph-starting-from-data-arrays). I am doing a very similar thing, but in D3.js v5. The aforementioned question only talks about v4. So I changed my code and this is how it looks like now.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js'></script>
    <script src='scripts/scriptzz.js'></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
      <svg id='map'><div class="tooltip"></div></svg>
      <svg id='linechart'></svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`scriptzz.js`

```
x_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y_data = [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
var lineInnerHeight = 100px; 
var lineInnerWidth = 100px;
 lineSvg = d3.select('#linechart');
 var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([Math.min(x_data), Math.max(x_data)]).range([0, lineInnerWidth]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([Math.min(y_data), Math.max(y_data)]).range([lineInnerHeight, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
      return x(x_data[i])
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
      return y(y_data[i])
  })

  let g = lineSvg.append('g')
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (lineInnerHeight) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
  
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
      .call(yAxis);

  g.selectAll('path')  
    .attr('d', line(x_data))
```

This still doesn't work for me. After an overnight session of frustration I'm here to see if some fresh pairs of eyes can look and point out my mistake. The place where I think I went wrong is the appending the axes and line to the `#linechart` div tag. Please feel free to ask for more information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with use of `Math.min` and `Math.max` in min max calculation as it is expecting numbers as an argument but not an array of numbers.

```js
let x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let y_data = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100];
let minX = d3.min(x_data);
let maxX = d3.max(x_data);
let minY = d3.min(y_data);
let maxY = d3.max(y_data);
let lineInnerHeight = 100;
let lineInnerWidth = 100;
lineSvg = d3.select('#linechart');

var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minX, maxX]).range([0, lineInnerWidth]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minY, maxY]).range([lineInnerHeight, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(x_data[i]);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return y(y_data[i]);
  });

let g = lineSvg.append('g');
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(35," + (lineInnerHeight) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(35,0)")
  .call(yAxis);

g.append('path')
  .attr('d', line(x_data))
  .attr("transform", "translate(35,0)");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>
  <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <svg id='map'><div class="tooltip"></div></svg>
    <svg id='linechart'></svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```